# Safari mobile - youtube iframe api - autoplay

Tags: mobile, youtube, safari, youtube-iframe-api, autoplay

I'm trying to get a Youtube video to autoplay on safari mobile using the YouTube iframe API. Here's my code:

```
<div class="player-wrapper featured-small featured-medium featured-large featured-xlarge">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
<script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          playerVars: {
            'controls': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'autoplay': 1,
            'loop': 1,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'playlist': '<?php echo $scales_hero_video; ?>'
          },
          videoId: '<?php echo $scales_hero_video; ?>',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady}
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

The video is supposed to autoplay and loop while being muted. But the video does not begin playing in safari mobile at all.

Comment: @milbrandt I've updated the description :)

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not allow autoplay or scripted playback in WebKit-based browsers on iOS-devices, this to prevent unwanted downloads over cellular network.

As mentioned in the YouTube Player API manual (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations):

> Mobile Considerations
>
> Autoplay and Scripted Playback
>   The HTML5  element, in certain mobile browsers (such as Chrome and Safari), only allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a user interaction (such as tapping on the player). Here's an excerpt from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html):
>
> > "Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."
>
> Due to this restriction, functions and parameters such as autoplay, playVideo(), loadVideoById() won't work in all mobile environments.

So what you want, autoplaying a video on Safari Mobile is not possible...

Sincerely,

Leon Hagendijk

Comment: Do you know if there is any effort underway to update this restriction?  For example, how about limiting the restriction to cellular-connected devices?  Or how about limiting it to manual start of the first video but allowing autoplay on subsequent videos (like a youtube playlist created from individual youtube + non-youtube links)?  Hoping that this situation improves before 5G gets here. WGQ

Comment: Thanks for the reference link, it's a good evident to show to my client :)

Comment: @Mcbeese I see my information was already semi-outdated: Autoplay and the Javascript .play()-function will be honored, but only when directly triggered by a User Action (eg. the (double)click, touchend, mousedown events): https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: This however, does not apply to the YouTube Player, since playback is called through a different JS call.

Comment: The video in the background of playoverwatch.com starts autoplaying on my iPhone X with 14.4. In the page source the video tag has autoplay turned on ... so it seems possible. Is it just a YouTube limitation?